# AWS S3 Policy Deny ListObjectVersions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, object-storage

I am using [Wasabi](http://wasabi.com). I have an s3 bucket with versioning enabled. **I want to be able to list all the objects that are not deleted**. My bucket contains the following objects:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

`c.txt` has been deleted.

I am accessing my s3 bucket with an IAM that follows the following policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:PutObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I list the object (`aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket`) it returns all the objects, included the deleted one (its latest version).

To prevent deleted objects from being listed, I tried to `deny` `s3:ListBucketVersions` on the root bucket and all objects but it did not work.

**How can I make the policy to prevent the user from listing previous versions / deleted objects?**

Edit: I am using Wasabi I just noticed that this behaviour is inconsistent with AWS S3 behaviour. I guess its on their side now.

Comment: I don't see deleted objects when running "aws s3 ls mybucket".

Comment: @jarmod you are right. I made an edit. It has to do with Wasabi API not AWS. I opened a ticket.